# Disable edittext if populated and setOnClickListener to edit the text

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I needed assistance with the edittext issue I am facing. When a new user comes in, edittext will respond normally. However, once the user saves his/her details and exit the application and come back to the same page; their details will be populated within the corresponding edittext. Now the issue is that I do not want the edittext to be enabled if their information is populated. I want to set a warning (alert dialog) before the user goes to change what's in the edittext. If the user hits yes to the warning, i want the edittext editable again.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_personal__information);

    fName = findViewById(R.id.personal_info_fName_ET);
    lName = findViewById(R.id.personal_info_lName_ET);
    userAge = findViewById(R.id.personal_info_userAge_ET);
    userPhone = findViewById(R.id.personal_info_userPhone_ET);

    getInfo();

    fName.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                    Personal_Information.this).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Make Changes");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Do you want to make these changes?");
            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "YES",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            //fName.setFocusable(true);
                        }
                    });
            alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "NO",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
            return false;
        }
    });

    submit = findViewById(R.id.personal_info_submit_btn);

    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            seralizePersonalInfo("Users Personal Info");
        }
    });
}
```

I want to disable the edittext in the "getInfo" method and enable it with an onClick method.

```
public void getInfo(){
    if (CurrentUserInfo.getFirstname() != null){
        fName.setText(CurrentUserInfo.getFirstname());
        lName.setText(CurrentUserInfo.getLastname());
        userAge.setText(CurrentUserInfo.getUserAge());
        userPhone.setText(CurrentUserInfo.getUserPhone());
    }
}
```

I've tried focuseable, disabling but the onClickListener is not responding with anything. I don't want to set the attribute in XML "focuseable = false" because i want the edittext to be focused if there are no details to display.
Thanks in advance and if you need further clarification, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

you can use below methods to achieve this

```
public void getInfo(){
    if (CurrentUserInfo.getFirstname() != null){
        fName.setText(CurrentUserInfo.getFirstname());
        lName.setText(CurrentUserInfo.getLastname());
        userAge.setText(CurrentUserInfo.getUserAge());
        userPhone.setText(CurrentUserInfo.getUserPhone());
        //do same for all edit text            
        fName.setKeyListener(null);
        fName.setLongClickable(false);
     }
}
```

and you want to enable it just give them a new callback reference.

```
 BaseKeyListener mBaseKeyListener = new BaseKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public int getInputType() {
        return 0;
    }
};

alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "YES",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        //do same for all edit text            
                        fName.setKeyListener(mBaseKeyListener);
                        fName.setLongClickable(true);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Just tried this mate, still not good. The edittext is not clickable for some reasons. It will not open the alert dialog.